# How to read a textfile and convert into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x

The question is to read a text file and return a dictionary like below.

this the text file

```
USER fjeen
```

NAME
Filcon Jeen

EMAIL filcon.jeen@clasic.edu.tr

PHONE 123-234-3333

This should be the return

{'fjeen':['Filcon jeen', 'filcon.jeen@clasic.edu.tr','123-234-3333']

This is what I've tried but does not seem to work.

```
dict={}
def read():
     with open("profiles.txt","r") as text:
         return dict(line.strip().split() for line in text)
```

the return i get is

```
{}
```

Please help

Comment: When you are assigning `dict={}` you are shadowing the built-in `dict` function. Remove the `dict={}` line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 4, in read
    #print 'Exiting sandbox process'
builtins.ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
shows this error

Comment: When you are splitting your lines, it looks like `.split()` is not returning a `key, value` pair. Instead of `return dict(line.strip().split() for line in text)`, try `return [line.strip().split() for line in text]`. That will return a list of the processed lines, and you can see if there are list items that are not `key, value` pairs. Once you find the problem in your text data, you can fix the data (or write some code to supply default values).